# Third party javascript code is only partially showing up in footer

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add some JavaScript of chamber of commerce logos to a footer and for some reason only one of the logos (javascript code) is showing up. I know these will be changed out every year, so I am decided to use a plugin to add the script to the footer instead of functions.php file. I don't know javascript very well, so I don't know if the code is bad, or what might be causing the issue.

This is the site: http://probitypools.com/

The plugin I am using: AddFunc Head & Footer Code

Here is the code I am trying to add (two different ones for two different locations of chamber of commerce groups):

```
    <div id="mni-membership-635911226845619403"></div>
    <script src="http://eocc.chambermaster.com/Content/Script/Member.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">new MNI.Widgets.Member("mni-membership-635911226845619403",{member:3833,styleTemplate:"#@id{text-align:center;position:relative}#@id .mn-widget-member-name{font-weight:700}#@id .mn-widget-member-logo{max-width:100%}"}).create();
    </script>

    <div id="mni-membership-635911228349496452"></div>
    <script src="http://maitlandchamber.chambermaster.com/Content/Scrip/Member.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">new MNI.Widgets.Member("mni-membership-635911228349496452",{member:308,styleTemplate:"#@id{text-align:center;position:relative}#@id .mn-widget-member-name{font-weight:700}#@id .mn-widget-member-logo{max-width:100%}"}).create();
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help!
Jules

Comment: Could it be the missing "t" in "Script" on the second src URL?

Comment: That is a good catch. However, it is just my typo typing it here in the forum and is not in the code on the website (I checked to make sure). Thanks for the feedback! I still don't know why it isn't letting both scripts show up.

Comment: If the two versions of the code use the same library, it's possible a conflict could arse where the second script attempts to overwrite the first one.